# Couldn't open module fglrx

Tags: drivers, kernel, xorg, radeon, fglrx

I was using `fglrx` driver long ago, but I switched to open-source driver. In the `Xorg.0.log` I'm getting following warnings.

```
[    35.380] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    35.416] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    35.518] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.518]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[    35.518]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[    35.518] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    35.518] Loading extension GLX
[    35.518] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 0
[    35.518] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[    35.518] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 2
[    35.518] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 3
[    35.518] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 4
[    35.518] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 5
[    35.518] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 6
[    35.518] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 7
[    35.518] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 8
[    35.518] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    35.518] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[    35.525] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fglrx
[    35.525] (II) UnloadModule: "fglrx"
[    35.525] (II) Unloading fglrx
[    35.525] (EE) Failed to load module "fglrx" (module does not exist, 0)
[    35.525] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    35.525] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[    35.526] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.526]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 7.3.0
[    35.526]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.526]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    35.526] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
[    35.526] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
[    35.565] (II) Module radeon: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.565]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 7.3.0
[    35.565]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.565]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    35.565] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    35.565] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    35.565] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.565]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[    35.565]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.565]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    35.565] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    35.566] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    35.566] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.566]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[    35.566]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.566]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    35.566] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    35.566] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[    35.566] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    35.566] (II) Unloading vesa
[    35.566] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[    35.566] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 0
[    35.566] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[    35.566] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 2
[    35.566] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 3
[    35.566] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 4
[    35.566] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 5
[    35.566] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 6
[    35.566] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 7
[    35.566] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 8
[    35.567] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    35.567] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[    35.567] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fglrx
[    35.567] (II) UnloadModule: "fglrx"
[    35.567] (II) Unloading fglrx
[    35.567] (EE) Failed to load module "fglrx" (module does not exist, 0)
[    35.567] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    35.567] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[    35.567] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.567]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 7.3.0
[    35.567]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.567]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    35.567] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    35.568] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    35.568] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.568]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[    35.568]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.568]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    35.568] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    35.568] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    35.568] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 0)
[    35.568] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    35.568] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    35.568] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.568]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[    35.568]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.568]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[    35.568] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    35.568] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    35.568] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[    35.568] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    35.569] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[    35.569] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    35.569] (II) Unloading vesa
[    35.569] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[    35.569] (II) RADEON: Driver for ATI Radeon chipsets:
```

But I'm not loading `fglrx` module.

```
ansh@ansh-HP:~$ grep -R 'fglrx' /etc/modprobe.d
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:#blacklist fglrx
```

And why is the kernel trying to load `fglrx` and `radeon` driver twice?

Comment: I'd check if there is /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

Comment: No such configuration file. Deleted all.

Comment: Do you have a `xorg.conf` in `/etc`? Start a search via `find /etc -name 'xorg.conf'`

Comment: No such file found in `/etc`.

Comment: Fairly sure you have an `xorg.conf` somewhere that has the wrong driver and gets sourced by `X`. Maybe checkout files like `~/.xinitrc` or explain how you start your `X`?

Comment: Nothing unusual in `~/.xinitrc`. What do you want to know about starting of `X`? I'm using the default Ubuntu settings.

Comment: I didn't manage to find the reason either. If anybody need *a workaround* — I created xorg config with `radeon` [like here](http://www.crazyengineers.com/threads/enable-dri3-for-amd-radeons-xorg-drivers.82217/) *(it could be either `xorg.conf`, or a file inside the `xorg.conf.d/` directory — doesn't matter)*.